# Why do many people in math use the phrase "almost always" when referring to irrational numbers vs rational numbers? (from a language perspective)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, terminology, convention

I understand what they mean by "almost always." E.G.:

Statement $A$ is true $\forall x∈ \mathbb{I}$.

Statement $A$ is false $\forall x∈ \mathbb{Q}$.

Therefore statement $A$ is almost always true...

But isn't that being purposefully coy? Instead of using the label of "almost always true," why not just be explicit?

Comment: Does $\mathbb{I} = \mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$, the irrational real numbers?

Comment: "Property $P$ holds a.e (almost everywhere) on $\Bbb{R}$" is much shorter to say than "There is a set $N\subset\Bbb{R}$ with (e.g. Lebesgue) measure zero such that for all $x\in \Bbb{R}\setminus N$, $P(x)$ holds". (Note that the set $N$ isn't unique). It's really just a convenience thing. Also, sometimes/usually, we don't really care about 'what' the exceptional set where the statement fails to hold is. Sometimes, we may just be interested in proving that there exists some $x$ where $P(x)$ holds. There are several reasons for why people say/do something; it's not always a deep reason.

Comment: Almost everywhere means with the exception of a set of measure zero.

Comment: There are cases where we don't even know what the exceptional set is, we just know that it's finite (or countable, or measure zero, or of lower dimension, or ...).

Comment: "Almost always," despite the sound, is a technical term: a property holds almost always iff the set of numbers for which it *doesn't* hold has [Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure) zero, or is *null*. (I've phrased this in terms of the real numbers with the most common choice of measure, but in fact every measure space has its own notion of "almost always," but you should first understand the "classical" setting of $\mathbb{R}$, or $\mathbb{R}^n$, with the Lebesgue measure.)

Answer (score 4):

The term [almost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost) is often used in mathematics. It refers to all but a negligible amount of elements in the set, but the notion of *negligible* depends on the context. For the term [almost everywhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere), negligible refers to a set of measure $0$, or contained in a set of measure $0$. For the term [almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely), used in probability, negligible means a set of probability $0$. For the term [almost all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_all), negligible usually refers to a finite set, but in topology, negligible often refers to a meagre set, and in number theory, [almost all positive integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely#Asymptotically_almost_surely) refers to "the positive integers in a set whose natural density is 1".

Conclusion, the meaning of the term *almost* depends on the context, but it turns out to be sufficiently convenient to have been adopted by say, *almost all* mathematicians...